# Email migration API limits

Tags: email, migration, limits, google-email-migration

In the documentation, it states that the API is limited to one email per user, and that we should create threads and process multiple users at once.
Does any one know if the is any other type of limitation? How many GB/Hour?
I have to plan a migration tens of thousands of accounts, hardware resources is practically unlimited, will I reaise a flag somewhere or get blocked if I start migrating over 1,000 users at a time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The limits for the API are posted at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-migration/limits. There is a per-user rate limit in place of one request per second per user. If you exceed this you will start seeing 503 errors returned. The best way to deal with this is to implement an exponential backoff algorithm to handle the errors and retry the request.